# filter dataframe by dict or json like column

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataframe like below:

```
       score           pvpdate
0      {2: 29, 4: 24}  2018-05-23
1      {2: 23, 4: 24}  2018-05-29
2      {2: 36, 4: 25}  2018-05-23
```

and I want to filter the score column and get a result like

```
     score1      score2     pvpdate
0        29          24     2018-05-23
1        23          24     2018-05-29
2        36          25     2018-05-23
```

How can I do this? I have tried the ways that score column like a json column, and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want columns names from keys of dictionaries extract column by [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html), use `DataFrame` contructor and change columns names by [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html), last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.oin.html) all columns without `score`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('score').values.tolist()).add_prefix('score').join(df)
print (df)
   score2  score4     pvpdate
0      29      24  2018-05-23
1      23      24  2018-05-29
2      36      25  2018-05-23
```

Anf if want columns names created by length of parsed DataFrame use `f-string`s:

```
#if stored dictionary like strings
df['score']=df['score'].map(ast.literal_eval) 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('score').values.tolist())
df1.columns = [f'score{i}' for i in range(1, len(df1.columns) + 1)]
df = df1.join(df)
print (df)
   score1  score2     pvpdate
0      29      24  2018-05-23
1      23      24  2018-05-29
2      36      25  2018-05-23
```

Comment: Wouldn't `df.pop('score').tolist()` work too? I.e. Unless for performance (marginal?) no need to drop down to NumPy.

Comment: @jpp - I think yes, sure. I add `.values` for better performance if big df.

Comment: I have already tried your way, but it still doesn't work, it still shows as before.I tried df[['score']] = df[['score',]].astype(str)  before apply your way, still doesn't work.

Comment: I found an answer import ast
    df['score']=df['score'].map(lambda d:ast.literal_eval(d))
    dfNew=df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['score'].to_dict()).T)

Comment: But still thank you so much though I still can't figure out why yours doesn't work

Comment: @张羽白 - Problem is my solution working with dictionaries in column `score`, in your real data are strings. So necessary convert them to dictionaries by `df['score']=df['score'].map(ast.literal_eval)`

Answer (score 0):

[Dictionary column in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29325458/dictionary-column-in-pandas-dataframe)
I found answer from this,by using 
    `import ast
    df['score']=df['score'].map(lambda d:ast.literal_eval(d))
    dfNew=df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['score'].to_dict()).T)`