# I want to convert the categorical variable to numerical in Python

Tags: python, list, dataframe, categorical-data

I have a dataframe having categorical variables. I want to convert them to the numerical using the following logic:

I have 2 lists one contains the distinct categorical values in the column and the second list contains the values for each category. Now i need to map these values in place of those categorical values.

For Eg:

```py
List_A = ['A','B','C','D','E']

List_B = [3,2,1,1,2]
```

I need to replace A with 3, B with 2, C and D with 1 and E with 2.

Is there any way to do this in Python.

I can do this by applying multiple for loops but I am looking for some easier way or some direct function if there is any.

Any help is very much appreciated, Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mapping dict

```
List_A = ['A','B','C','D','E',]

List_B = [3,2,1,1,2]
d=dict(zip(List_A, List_B))

new_list=['A','B','C','D','E','A','B']
new_mapped_list=[d[v] for v in new_list if v in d]
new_mapped_list
```

Or define a function and use [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

```
List_A = ['A','B','C','D','E',]

List_B = [3,2,1,1,2]

d=dict(zip(List_A, List_B))

def mapper(value):
    if value in d:
        return d[value]
    return None

new_list=['A','B','C','D','E','A','B']
map(mapper,new_list)
```

Comment: Thanks mad_ this is really helpful and exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose df is your data frame and "Category" is the name of the column holding your categories:

```
df[df.Category == "A"] = 3,2, 1, 1, 2
df[(df.Category == "B") | (df.Category == "E") ] = 2
df[(df.Category == "C") | (df.Category == "D") ] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks shweta24 but this will work if I have only 5-6 categories in my column. But in my dataset there are 000's of categories.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to replace values in one list with the values of other and the structure is like the one you say. Two list, same lenght and same position, then you only need this:

```
list_a = []
list_a = list_b
```

A more convoluted solution would be like this, with a function that will create a dictionary that you can use on other lists:

```
# we make a function
def convert_list(ls_a,ls_b):
    dic_new = {}
    for letter,number in zip(ls_a,ls_b):
        dic_new[letter] = number
    return dic_new
```

This will make a dictionary with the combinations you need. You pass the two list, then you can use that dictionary on other list:

```
List_A = ['A','B','C','D','E']
List_B = [3,2,1,1,2]

dic_new = convert_list(ls_a, ls_b)

other_list = ['a','b','c','d']

for _ in other_list:
    print(dic_new[_.upper()])

# prints
3
2
1
1
```

cheers

Comment: `A` equivalent value should be 3 not 1.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a solution from machine learning scikit-learn module.

```
OneHotEncoder

LabelEncoder
```

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html

The pandas "hard" way:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29330853/9799449

Comment: This is not relevant